# Call Azure Function with ServiceBusTrigger via HTTP throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

In our deployed environment, we will have an Azure Function that is triggered via ServiceBus, which is great. But for local testing, I want to be able to make use of the following advice from the [following article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local):

> For all kinds of functions other than HTTP triggers and webhooks, you can test your functions locally by calling an administration endpoint. Calling this endpoint with an HTTP POST request on the local server triggers the function. You can optionally pass test data to the execution in the body of the POST request. This functionality is similar to the Test tab in the Azure portal.

However, when I do said post request to `localhost:7071/admin/functions/NameOfMyFunction`, the following exception gets thrown from within the Azure code:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'No authentication handler is configured to authenticate for the scheme: ArmToken'

For functions with `ServiceBusTrigger` on them, is there some Authentication header that I need to put on this test HTTP post?

Answer (score 2):

> For functions with ServiceBusTrigger on them, is there some Authentication header that I need to put on this test HTTP post?

It odd that you get that error. Based on my test, there is no need to add authentication header for it. I test it with VS 2017,it works correctly on my side.

The following is my detail steps, you could refer to:

1.Create an azure function app and add service bus trigger.

[image]

2.Test it with postman

```
post localhost:7071/admin/functions/{functionName}
```

**body**

```
{"input":"Service Bus Message"}
```

[image]

Console output:
[image]